# How do I programmatically set an ADO variable to a ForEach loop enumerator in SSIS?

Tags: .net, ssis, ado

I am creating an SSIS package programmatically using the SSIS Object Model.

I want to have a ForEach Loop using an ADO object variable I've created as the enumerator. How do I assign the variable to the enumerator and use its values inside the loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assumptions:

- You have a ADO object variable **User::ADOObject** containing two columns *Key* and *Value*.

Code:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Enumerators;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Enumerators.ADO;

ForEachLoop f = new ForEachLoop();
ForEachADOEnumerator ado_enum = (ForEachADOEnumerator) f.ForEachEnumerator.InnerObject;
ado_enum.Type = ADOEnumerationType.EnumerateRowsInFirstTable;
ado_enum.DataObjectVariable = "User::ADOObject";

f.VariableMappings.Add();
f.VariableMappings[0].VariableName = "User::Key";
f.VariableMappings[0].ValueIndex = "Key";

f.VariableMappings.Add();
f.VariableMappings[1].VariableName = "User::Value";
f.VariableMappings[1].ValueIndex = "Value";
```

If you are using [EzAPI](https://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/21238), first you must modify the EzAPI source as the *EzForEachLoop* class doesn't expose **VariableMappings** out of the box. Add this property to the EzForEachLoop class in EzExecutables.cs:

```
public ForEachVariableMappings VariableMappings
{
    get { return (m_exec as ForEachLoop).VariableMappings; }

}
```

And then in your code initialize the *EzForEachLoop* like so (assuming this is called within a custom package class, the "this" argument in the constructor refers to that package):

```
EzForEachLoop ezf = new EzForEachLoop(this); 
ezf.Initialize(ForEachEnumeratorType.ForEachADOEnumerator);
```

And now **ezf**'s enumerator and variable mappings can be set in the same manner as the *ForEachLoop* **f** above.